# show content to another site

Tags: javascript

i want to need to make script like google adsence(just example) java script..we are just pasting java script of ad in our site..it will become ad...like that i want to make javascript that..in my site ( www.momdb.com ) have different movie details...for every movie i need javascript..if any one copy that javascript and paste into his site there want to show that movies basic details (like,that movies director,producer,actors,etc)..its all in my databse...how i can show that to his site if he copy paste javascript..?
how i can do this with javascript ?? no need of iframe..because,javascript will work every where...give me some basic idea..or a tutorial for that

Thnks friends :)

Comment: Did you try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+widget+tutorial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have other sites include Javascript from your site with the `<script>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://momdb.com/embed.js'></script>
```

Depending on what `embed.js` contains, the user's site can be modified / parsed according to your needs.

Assume `embed.js` contains the following code

```
document.write("Hello world");
```

Both this markup,

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://momdb.com/embed.js'></script>
</body>
```

and this markup

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write("Hello World");
    </script>
</body>
```

Would produce the *exact* same result

Answer (score -3):

You can't.  There is this security feature browser have called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that prevents a piece of javascript from accessing service that it didn't originate from.  Origination is by the page served not the URL of the script tag.  So if you have a page served from your web server (ie http://www.momdb.com), any javascript on that page can only make connections back to http://www.momdb.com.  It can't even access https://www.momdb.com because that is a different origin.  There are work arounds to this limitation, but they have other security concerns you should research.  So this is why iframes are still necessary because an iframe within a page can set a new origin.

Comment: I think if someone includes a script with source mombdb.com, the script on momdb.com would have full access to the page from where it was included.. so if on domain.com you add `<script src='http://momdb.com/test.js'></script>` , test.js would now have the same access to domain.com as any other 'local' script would have .. thats how adsense / analytics work

Comment: I wasn't talking about access to the page, but the ability to perform xhr back to the other server.  Yes it has page access, but I assumed he was asking about making xhr calls to another server which would be disallowed by the same origin policy.

Comment: right, I don't think OP mentioned XHR though, hence my answer.. and although maybe uncommon, he can pass data to the server by injecting other script tags after the initial `test.js` eg.. <script src='http://domain.com/sendData.php?data=foobar'></script> .. the php script can then reply with other Javascript code etc..

Comment: Well his "question" was so nebulous I had to do a lot of guessing about their intentions.  It just wasn't clear exactly what he wanted.